# Зависимость от класса

Tags: php, laravel

Все привет.

Возник такой вопрос. Как лучше использовать класс внутри метода моего контроллера? Код ниже:

```
<?php

namespace app\Controller;

use app\Models\Territory;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->checkSessionAndViewConnection();

        $objTerritory = new Territory();

        View::generate('form', $this->getConfiguration(), json_encode($objTerritory->getArea()));
    }
}
```

Получается, что метод зависит от этого класса. Я очень хочу научиться правильно писать код.

Если я правильно понимаю, то за это отвечает один из принципов SOLID (инверсия зависимостей), но я немного не понимаю когда применять его.

У меня есть три варианта использовать сторонний класс в методе:

1. Как и сейчас у меня сделанно.
2. Передать объект класса как аргумнтом в метод.
3. Создать private свойство в контроллере и при создании объекта контролера в методе __construct присваивать в это свойство объект класса и дальше его использовать.

Можете пожалуйста подсказать мне, как правильно делать в такой ситуации?

Comment: 1) чем это плохо? 2) тогда зависеть от класса будет тот, кто вызывает этот метод 3) чем это будет отличаться от 1 ?

Comment: По-моему все-таки  это должно быть свойством класса

Comment: А это что, при регистрации пользователя за ним закрепляется какой-то объект с территорией?

Comment: При регистрации пользователь должен ввести имя, email, область, город и район.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте trait `GenerateForm`. Подключите в любой контроллер где необходима генерация данной формы регистрации. `use GenerateForm` и вызывайте нужные методы для обработки. пример:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use GenerateForm;

    public function index()
    {
        ...
        return $this->generateForm($this->getConfiguration());
    }
}


// TRAIT
...
use app\Models\Territory;
trait GenerateForm {
    public function generateForm($config) {
        $objTerritory = new Territory();

        return View::generate('form', $config, json_encode($objTerritory->getArea()));
    }
}
```

тем самым Вам не нужно создавать объект класса для жесткой привязки. Данный объект будет создавать трейт в случае необходимости. Ну если я правильно понял задачу.